# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0} (\frac {(1+x)^{\frac 1x}}{e})^{\frac{1}{\sin x}}$

Tags: limits

Can I get a starting hint to solve this? The second index of $\frac{1}{\sin x}$ is throwing me off and I really don’t know what to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call this $L$, then evaluate $\ell:=\ln L$ viz.$$\ell=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tfrac1x\ln(1+x)-1}{\sin x}.$$Various methods show the numerator (denominator) is asymptotic to $-\tfrac12x$ ($x$), so $\ell=-\tfrac12$ i.e. $L=\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$.

Edit: as requested, here's an approach not using the Maclaurin series of $\ln(1+x)$. By L'Hôpital's rule,$$\frac{\ln(1+x)-x}{x\sin x}\sim\frac{1/(1+x)-1}{x\cos x+\sin x}=\frac{-1/(1+x)}{\cos x+\tfrac{\sin x}{x}}\to\frac{-1}{1+1}=-\tfrac12.$$

Comment: I am getting $l=0$, what now? Since $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln{1+x}}{x}$

Comment: @Aditya Double-check your reasoning. The numerator is $(x-x^2/2+o(x^2))/x-1$, i.e. $-x/2+o(x)$.

Comment: Can u give an alternative that does not use expansion?

Comment: @Aditya See edit.

Answer (score 0):

$$y=\Big[\frac {(1+x)^{\frac 1x}}{e}\Big]^{\frac{1}{\sin (x)}}\implies \log(y)={\frac{1}{\sin (x)}}\log\Big[\frac {(1+x)^{\frac 1x}}{e}\Big]={\frac{\log(1+x)-x}{x\sin (x)}}$$ Using the standard expansions of $\log(1+x)$ and $\sin(x)$, we then have
$$\log(y)=\frac {\left(x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+O\left(x^5\right) \right)-x } {x\left(x-\frac{x^3}{6}+O\left(x^5\right) \right) }$$ that is to say
$$\log(y)=\frac {-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+O\left(x^5\right) } {x^2-\frac{x^4}{6}+O\left(x^6\right) }$$ The limit of $\log(y)$ is already obvious but let us constinue with the long division to get
$$\log(y)=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x}{3}-\frac{x^2}{3}+O\left(x^3\right)$$
$$y=e^{\log(y)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}\left(1+\frac{x}{3}-\frac{5 x^2}{18}+O\left(x^3\right)\right)$$ which shows the limit and also how it is approached.

Moreover, this gives a short cut calculation of the unpleasant expression. Trying for $x=0.1$ (this is very far from $0$), the exact value is $0.625149$ while the truncated expression gives $\frac{371}{360 \sqrt{e}}=0.625064$.

Answer (score -1):

I did the following within my CAS:

[image]

Then I did

[image: Expansion of 1/Sin[x] for small x]

```
Limit[((1 + x)^(1/x)/E)^(1/x), x -> 0]
```

(*   1/Sqrt[Exp[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Cvxd.png)] *)

```
Limit[((1 + x)^(1/x)/E)^(x/6), x -> 0]
1
```

Make use of the rule that if a limit is a product of two limits than the limit of the product exists and is the product of the limits. Calculation rules with limits in general. The rest is even more 1 for small x approaching 0.

```
N@(1/Sqrt[E])
0.606531

Table[((1 + x)^(1/x)/E)^(1/Sin[x]), {x, 0.0001, 0.0003, 0.0001}]
{0.606551, 0.606571, 0.606591}

ListLinePlot@
 Table[{x, ((1 + x)^(1/x)/E)^(1/Sin[x])}, {x, 0.0001, 0.0003, 0.0001}]
```

[image]

For small x this has an affine representation.

```
Series[((1 + x)^(1/x)/E)^(1/Sin[x]), {x, 0, 2}]
SeriesData[x, 0, {
 E^Rational[-1, 2], Rational[1, 3] E^Rational[-1, 2], 
  Rational[-5, 18] E^Rational[-1, 2]}, 0, 3, 1]
```